# ASP.NET MVC: Need help putting a form inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a heck of time trying to figure out how to put a form inside of a bootstrap modal.  I think my problem is when I try and return something from the controller.  But you may spot some other problem with how I'm doing this.   Here's what I've got:

**The Parent View:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modalAE" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3><strong>Edit Account Profile - <span class="accountname"></span></strong></h3>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountProfileEdit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-accountedit-appt", @class = "full-form" }))
            {
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_AccountProfileEdit.cshtml", new namespace.Models.AccountProfileEditViewModel())
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="accountprofileedit-submit" name="accountprofileedit-submit" value="Edit Account" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px;">Edit Account</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Partial View (slimmed down):**

```
@model namespace.Models.AccountProfileEditViewModel  

@Html.CustomTextboxFor(model => model.Address)
```

**The Partial View's Model (also slimmed down):**

```
public class AccountProfileEditViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public AccountProfileEditViewModel() { }
}
```

**The Partial View's Controller:**

*Note the question embedded in the code: WHAT DO I PUT HERE?*

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AccountProfileEdit([Bind]AccountProfileEditViewModel model)
    {

        if (Request.Form["accountprofileedit-submit"] != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // logic to store form data in DB
            }
        }
        return PartialView(**WHAT DO I PUT HERE??**, model);
    }
```

No matter what I put here, it goes wrong. If I put the path to the partial view:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_AccountProfileEdit.cshtml", model);
```

Then after the form is submitted, it just spits the html of the partial view onto the screen, totally out of context.   But if I try this:

```
return PartialView("AccountProfileEdit", model);
```

I get an error: The partial view 'AccountProfileEdit' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Comment: What do you want to happen after the form is successfully submitted?

Comment: Jasen, I really appreciate you taking the time to chip in.  I think I can handle a successful submission.  The modal will close and I'll fill in the logic that right now says " // logic to store form data in DB".  What I'm actually struggling with right now is when ModelState.IsValid = false.  The modal just closes.  It doesn't stay open to show any of the validations.

Comment: Then you don't want a standard form submission. As soon as you submit the browser navigates away and closes your modal. You'll need to do an AJAX post and catch the response back from the server before closing the modal yourself.

Comment: Your last attempt is almost correct `return PartialView("AccountProfileEdit", model)`. It's looking for `AccountProfileEdit.chtml` so you want `PartialView("_AccountProfileEdit", model)`

Comment: @Jasen is correct. Typically with a modal form, you use ajax to post the values if you want to stay on the same page. Currently you just attempting to redirect to partial view which would not make sense. You would need to redirect to the original method that generated the main view

Comment: Ok, thanks Jasen and Stephen.  I'll look too, but if either of you know of any examples or tutorials, please share!!

Comment: I created a new, more generic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053460/how-to-make-a-net-mvc-form-inside-a-modal-using-jquery-with-validation