# How to update my View after Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am in MVC environment and I am calling one of my Controller methods from my View. Controller method subsequently does some validation check and returns to the same view with **faulty modelstate**

At this point, I am expecting all of my validation fields which look like following:

```
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comments)</td>
```

to light up with error messages. That is not happening. I think it is because I need to reload the view with new **faulty Model**. How can I do that?

Following is snipped from my Ajax code:

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
        var model = {
            ApplicationNumber: '@Model.ApplicationNumber',
            ApplicationId :'@Model.ApplicationId' ,
            Name: $('#Name').val(),
            CreateDate: $('#CreateDate').val(),
            OverrideHireDate: $('#OverrideHireDate').val(),
            Amount: $('#Amount').val(),
            VendorId: $('#Vendor').val(),
            Comments: $('#Comments').val(),
            CurrentState: '@Model.CurrentState',
            CurrentStatusDate: '@Model.CurrentStatusDate'
    };
        $.ajax({
            data: model,
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveApplication", "Applications")',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                $(function () {
                    // some code to activate validation controls?
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Following is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveApplication(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               // ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This is a Test");
                return View("New",application);
            }

            ApplicationBLL.SaveApplication(application);
            return Content(string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried the jquery validate () method before calling your jquery post?

Comment: You are returning a "New" view, is that "New" view's razor also equipped to display the errors? Or is it only on the originating view that you have validationmessagefor written?

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31064411/2030565) for a similar question. It's for a modal but the idea is the same.

Comment: Did you enabled Unobtrusive JavaScript validation?

Comment: @SubhashDike: "New" view is the originating one. I am just sending controller back to where ti came from.

Comment: @Coffeebean , just to see if this is validation returning issue or it's just a display issue, can you try putting this on the top  @Html.ValidationSummary(true) so that we can at least see if you are getting errors at all

Comment: If I was you I would use Ajax.BeginForm , then check the AjaxOptions like UpdateTargetId and InsertionMode

Comment: Also why do you have an onready jquery thing inside of your success? It's not going to stop it from working but really your should be putting your onready around the thing that creates the onclick binding not inside of your code.

Comment: Assuming you have client side validation enabled, handle the forms `.submit()` event and check `$('form').valid()` - if `false`, cancel the default submit and exit the function without making the ajax call. And you can simplify you code by just using `data: '$('form').serialize(),` which will do what your `var model = {...}` is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok May be this was very trivial but this did the trick.

In the OnSuccess of the AJAX Post I did put following and it worked:

```
 $("body").html(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

If Your values are updated at database or you get the values at controller and you just need to add the following code in the success function of ajax call,,

```
location.reload(true);
```

this will work...