# MVC with modals page is redirecting wrongly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I trying to use Ajax to submit my forms to the MVC server. The reason is because I want the errors to pup up in my modal and not redirect me.

When I post to the controller and when the model is good and validated I call to `redirectToAction("Index")`but for some reason it just sends the redirect action into my modal window (where my invalid model would go)... It is sending it there because that is where the ajax success goes, but I don't want it to go there if the page is successful.

I want the whole page to redirect in that case. How can I simply redirect and forget the modal at the point of success? If it seems unclear what I am asking, I can provide more detail.

**Here is how I am submitting my form.**

```
$("#newForm").on("submit", "#form", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent standard form submission
        console.log("ajax successfully called.");
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            method: form.attr("method"),  // post
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (partialResult) {
                $("#newForm").html(partialResult);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: On a success you could close the modal first. Then call your MVC action?

Comment: Can you not just add something like this into your success block:  window.location.href = "/now/go/here";

Comment: I don't think so. Here is the example I am following for form validation. In this example he calls a success partial view. In place of the success I am trying to redirect the whole page. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31064411/5874935

Comment: I guess on a basic level you could check the returned data for a specific value only populated on successful validation then redirect according to whether it is present or not?

Comment: I decided to go ahead an make it return a success partial view. Is there a way I could make it look at the parent modal of the succecss partial view and then hide the parent? Effectively closing the modal???

Comment: Your making an ajax call and ajax calls never redirect - the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page (using `RedirectToAction("Index")` will not work). If you ultimately want to redirect if successful, then do not use ajax, make a normal submit (and return the view if not successful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it was all said and done here was the issue. An ajax call returns content and my controller was returning a view. So, the answer that I used to fix this is in my controller if there was a success I returned null and in the else that needed to return the view for an invalid model state or what have you.

Finally on the view portion in the ajax call I added an if statement inside the success block that  checked for the returned `data` variable and read if `data.length === 0` do one thing and else do nothing. This is how I controlled the modal, loaders, etc is by how much content was returned in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line you can check the result if it was a success or not by adding a json value to it like so.

Controller:

```
{
  // your logic
  return Json(new { success = true, data = redirectToAction("Index") });
  // or
  return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

Ajax:

```
success: function (partialResult) {
            if(partialResult.success)
            {   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $("#newForm").html(partialResult.data);
            }
            else
                $("#newForm").html(partialResult.data);
        }
```

So when you know the result is a success you hide the modal window and apply your redirect at that point. Otherwise, you simply show the error. (Edit)

Comment: this is a pretty good answer...I am not sure why or how I down voted it at the time. Make some sort of edit so I can give it an up vote.